# Download old image from Upwork

Tags: php, upwork-api

I downloaded a lot of data from my account on Upwork, including screenshot images. Now I'm trying to access those images (I want to download them) but the request token is expired.
This is how it looks like currently:

```
screenshot_img_lrg: "https://agora-tracker-prod.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tracker_resized/s/######/2017/12/2/########-lrg?X-Amz-Security-Token=some_long_token&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20171228T093730Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Credential=some_credential&X-Amz-Signature=some_signature",
```

This is just a screenshot part from my json file (the rest is private data).
I would like to know if there is any way to download this image without redownloading the whole set of data (last time I redownloaded this data my Upwork app was banned).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to download a batch of images using Upwork API.

You may also want to check [Get Work Diary](https://developers.upwork.com/#companies-and-teams_get-work-diary) and/or [Get Work Diary by Contract](https://developers.upwork.com/#companies-and-teams_get-work-diary-by-contract) API. Both can return a number of records for the specific period - in that way, you can minimize the number of requests.

If it doesn't suit your needs, try to contact [Support Team](https://support.upwork.com) and explain the situation and the reason why you need to grab all that images.